# Wrong Date and Time being returned using CURRENT_DATE, Now() & CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - Off by 1 day/stuck at 23:00

Tags: node.js, postgresql

Oddly enough, when I check the terminal, the correct date is being displayed. aka 2021-04-15.
However, when I return it to my front end using the same query, the date and time is wrong. (There isnt a timestamp in the terminal but there is one in the returned results front end.
This is my code for returning to front end.

```
//get staff records
app.get("/admin/staff/display", async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const allStaffDetails = await pool.query("SELECT firstname, lastname, phonenumber, date FROM staff ORDER BY staff_id");
        const allStaffDetails = await pool.query("SELECT * FROM staff ORDER BY staff_id");
        (I dont use both of these querys at once, but both return the incorrect values)
        res.json(allStaffDetails.rows);
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error.message);
    }
});
```

My front end is returning the data in the following format - 2021-04-14T23:00:00.000Z. Its currently the 15th in the UK and its (at time of writing) and its 12.04pm.
Ideally, I dont want the timestamp being recorded/returned at all.
Only the date.

Comment: What data type is the column `date`? (which btw. is  a horrible name). If that is defined as `date` (the data type) then your application is formatting the date incorrectly as there is no time stored in such a column. What programming language is that?

Comment: Ill work on my naming conventions XD.
Data type is date. Using node.js

Comment: The reason why it's a bad name is that it doesn't document what kind of data that is. A "due date"? A "registration date"? A "birth date"? A "discharge date"? A "hire date"?

Comment: Thanks for the heads up. Im going to move this over to node.js section as it seems to be related to it rather than postgres!

Comment: What is the configuration for TimeZone? In SQL: show TimeZone;

Comment: Im sorry @FrankHeikens Im not sure what you mean? The datatype is date and the default value is Current_Date?

Comment: Yes, I understand, what time zone is set for the database or even database connection? Ask your database by executing this piece of SQL: SHOW timezone;

Comment: Ah apologies. Timezone of postgres is UTC. My server is hosted in Ireland which puts the postgres db 1 hour behind. Ive tried updating the timezone using SET timezone=+1; though I read that this resets?
Even with updating that, no change happenes to my frontend time being returned.